# How to calculate annihilation cross section, given effective operator for Datk Matter?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, effective-field-theory

Suppose I have an effective operator of the form $\frac{1}{\Lambda^{2}}$$\bar{\chi}\chi\bar{q}q$, where $\chi$ is an fermionic DM and *'q'* is the quark. Given this operator, How do I calculate the DM DM $\rightarrow$ SM SM annihilation cross section? What will be the *S-matrix* element squared, i.e, $|\mathcal M|^{2}$? It would be of immense help if someone could post showing the calculation in detail.

Thank you.